# Turn flag on/off to change name

Tags: vba, excel

I need help.

I have words and numbers in column A3:A500
and I need to change their names.
if a cell contains the word "previ" than put in a new column the letter "p" if the cells is a number. if its a word then dont put "p"
...like turning a flag on and off.

This is what i have:

```
Sub()
For i=3 to 500   
  x= range("a:"&i).value
  If x contains "previ" Then
    prevflag=1
  ElseIf x is not integer Then
    prevflag=0
  End If

  If prevflag=1 Then 
    range("H:"& i )= "p"
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Can you guys help me make this work?
and thank you!!
this is what it needs to look like
https://postimg.org/image/e62z4xwlj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your example, it looks like you want to put the "p" in rows in a section with a header that contains "previ" but not in a section with a header that doesn't. You also seem to want "p" in rows which have a blank in column A, not just integers. Does the below work for you?

```
Public Sub addPs()

    Dim previFlag As Boolean

    Dim c As Range: For Each c In Range("a1:a51")

        If InStr(c.Value, "previ") > 0 Then

            previFlag = True

        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(c.Value) Then

            previFlag = False

        End If

        If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then

            If Int(c.Value) = c.Value And previFlag Then c.Offset(0, 3) = "p"

        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: YYYYEESSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

thank you man !!!!!!!!! u rock !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you may be after something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    iRow = 3
    Do
        If InStr(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, "previ") > 0 Then '<--| if current cell contains "previ
            iRow = iRow + 1 '<--| then  then start scanning for numeric values
            Do
                If IsNumeric(Cells(iRow, 1).Value) Then Cells(iRow, 3).Value = "p" '<--| if current cell is numeric then write "p" two cells left of it
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Loop While InStr(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, "Type") = 0 And iRow <= lastRow
        Else
            iRow = iRow + 1 '<--| else skip to next row
        End If
    Loop While iRow <= lastRow
End Sub
```

just change the column offset to your needs (you wrote column "H" but your example has "p"s in column "C")

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the cases, but still, this is how you check for numeric values:

```
?isnumeric(6)
True
?isnumeric("test")
False
```

In your code:

```
else if not isnumeric(x) then
```

Comment: like, once a cells has the word "previ" then put in new column the word "p" in all cells below that are numbers.
but if there are words then dont wright "p"
the link shows what i need it to look like
https://postimg.org/image/e62z4xwlj/

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to be done with VBA? You could put this formula in H3 and paste it down to H500:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("previ",A3)),"","p")
```

However, this doesnt deal with your number criteria, but I don't know what you mean by that. If a cell contains "previ", that cell is not numeric. It may have some numeric digits in it somewhere, but "previ04578" is not a number. Could you share some sample data? Failing that you can check for any numeric digit with stacked substitutions and a length comparison, for example:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("previ",A3)),"",IF(LEN(A1)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"0",""),"9",""),"8",""),"7",""),"6",""),"5",""),"4",""),"3",""),"2",""),"1","")),"p",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative...

```
Sub FlagRows()
    Dim i As Long, val As Variant, bFlag As Boolean: bFlag = False

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To 500
            val = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            bFlag = IIf(Not IsNumeric(val), IIf(InStr(CStr(val), "previ"), True, False), bFlag)
            If IsNumeric(val) And bFlag = True Then .Cells(i, 4).Value = "p"
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```